# Scaling a sphere in unidirectional using any of the transform controls

Tags: three.js

I would like to increase/decrease the sphere's radius in threejs using transform controls. I do not want to scale in only -x -y or z directions, and I want all of them to work the same way.

I know that when I enable all 3, the middle(fourth) handles scales uniformly. Disabling any of the handles makes the fourth handle also disabled.

Is there a way to make this happen nicely so that I can simply print out the scaling factor(basically radius when radius is 1)?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Ever manage to figure out how to do this?